# what is the command to see the revision of individual files under a folder in svn?

Tags: svn, revision

I happen to have different revision of files (svn) under a folder. Is there any command to show what is the revision of each of the files I have? 
I know I can do a `svn st -uq` but that only shows the files that are different from the server, and I would like to know the revisions independent if there is a newer version or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svn ls -v URL|PATH`

```
>svn ls -v http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/
     36 lazybadg              янв 09 11:45 ./
     34 lazybadg           42 мар 24  2012 Dr?p?r.ma?ar.sv?nskan.man.eller.smalensk?n.txt
     32 lazybadg           88 дек 27  2011 Hello.de.txt
     33 lazybadg           82 фев 28  2012 Hello.en.txt
     36 lazybadg           88 янв 09 11:45 Hello.eo.txt
     35 lazybadg           90 янв 09 11:35 Hello.fr.txt
```

First column in output is file-revision

Answer (score 1):

You can use `svn info` for this purpose. The following command prints information for each file in the current directory - including the revision your are looking for:

```
svn info --depth files | grep '^Path: \|^Revision: '
```

If you want to format the output, I recommend using the option `--xml` and piping the output to script that parses the XML and prints the fields in a readable manner. The following listing contains a simple example how that can be done in Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys, lxml.etree
document = lxml.etree.parse(sys.stdin.buffer)
for entry in document.xpath('//entry[@kind="file"]'):
    print(entry.xpath('string(@path)'), entry.xpath('string(@revision)'))
```

Comment: Came up with same thing. +1 for including the Python script.